# WebRTC - connection between two different web browsers

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

So, I have a WebRTC web app with audio, video, chat and file sharing. Everything works fine on chrome: PC-to-PC, Mobile-to-PC. I've also added the latest version of adapter.js to the html file.
When trying to test communication between different web browsers, everything pretty much fails.
Tested the following scenarios:

1. Test 1
   Firefox/Edge = Caller
   Chrome = Answerer

Video is visible on Caller's side, but on Answerer's side I get the following error:

> DOMException: Could not start video source

2. Test 2
   Chrome = Caller
   Firefox/Edge = Answerer

Video is visible on Callers side, but on Answerers side nothing happens.

As stated above, I've adapter.js in the html file, also I've added stun/turn servers when creating a new PeerConnection.

If anyone has any ideas about this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have to enable DTLS-SRTP, this can be done by passing the following option to the PeerConnection constructor:

{ 'optional': [{'DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement': 'true'}]}

Comment: Still not working. Same problem persists.